# javaFX media crash in loop with because of ERROR_GSTREAMER_PIPELINE_STATE_CHANGE

Tags: java, javafx, gstreamer

I can successfully play the media file, but when I play it in a loop, it always crashes after few seconds. I debugged it, and found original error is "com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaError:ERROR_GSTREAMER_PIPELINE_STATE_CHANGE"

JDK15, language level:10, javafx 11

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
   String file =  new File("shoot.wav").toURI().toString();
    while (true) {
        Media media = new Media(file);
        MediaPlayer mediaPlayer = new MediaPlayer(media);
        mediaPlayer.play();

        try {
            Thread.sleep(50);
        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

the exception:

```
Caused by: MediaException: UNKNOWN : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player! : com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaException.exceptionToMediaException(MediaException.java:146)
at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:518)
at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.<init>(MediaPlayer.java:421)
at org.openjfx/org.openjfx.App.main(App.java:35)
... 11 more
Caused by: com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaException: Could not create player!
at javafx.media/com.sun.media.jfxmediaimpl.NativeMediaManager.getPlayer(NativeMediaManager.java:295)
at javafx.media/com.sun.media.jfxmedia.MediaManager.getPlayer(MediaManager.java:118)
at javafx.media/javafx.scene.media.MediaPlayer.init(MediaPlayer.java:474)
... 13 more
Exception running application org.openjfx.App
```

Comment: curious: do you really want to create and play a new player every 50ms?

Comment: I am using this to simplify my code in which  eneny tanks need to randomly shoot @kleopatra